# Is Wilks' Theorem (the LRT is asymptotically chi-squared-distributed) not applicable to logistic regression because of no absolute continuity?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, solution-verification, chi-squared, logistic-regression

Wilks' Theorem is given in the source below as Theorem 12.4.2, p. 515. It is part of the chapter "Quadratic Mean Differentiable Families" where parametric families $\{P_{\theta}, \theta \in \Omega\}$ are considered and $\Omega$ is assumed to be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$. In the beginning of the chapter (p. 492), it is assumed that each $P_{\theta}$ is absolutely continuous with respect to a $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$, and set $p_{\theta} = dP_{\theta}/d\mu(x)$.

In logistic regression, the unknown variable is usually called $\beta$ instead of $\theta$ and $n$ observations of the form $\{X_i,Y_i\}$ are considered where $X_i \in \mathbb{R}^k$ and $Y_i \in \{0,1\}$. So far, I've been mistakenly thinking that the assumption that each $P_{\theta}$ is absolutely continuous is fulfilled in the logistic regression with

$$p_{\beta} = \frac{e^{X_i^T \beta Y_i}}{1 + e^{X_i^T \beta}}.$$

However, I've come to think about whether $p_{\beta}$ is a probability density function and realized that it is not since it does not integrate to $1$.

I noticed that $p_{\beta}$ comes from assuming that $Y_i$ is Bernoulli($p_i$)-distributed with $p_i = \frac{e^{ti}}{1 + e^{ti}}, t_i = X_i^T\beta $ and then we have that

$$p_{\beta}(y) = dP_{\beta}/d\mu(y) = p_i^{Y_i}(1-p_i)^{1-Y_i} = \frac{e^{X_i^T\beta Y_i}}{1 + e^{X_i^T \beta}}.$$

So, I've realized it is a probability mass function, not a probability density function and the distribution in consideration is thus not absolutely continuous.

Does that mean that Wilks' Theorem is not applicable to logistic regression?

**Source:** E.L. Lehmann and J. P. Romano, "Testing Statistical Hypotheses", Springer Science+Business Media, 2008. It is freely accessible here: https://sites.stat.washington.edu/jaw/COURSES/580s/582/HO/Lehmann_and_Romano-TestingStatisticalHypotheses.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the fact that your formula is for a probability mass function does not estop or rule out the use of Wilks's theorem here.

The easy-to-overlook boilerplate language "$P_\theta$  is absolutely continuous with respect to a $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$, and set $p_\theta=dP_\theta/d\mu(x)$" is your friend here. In this case one usually picks counting measure for $\mu$, which assigns mass $1$ to each integer.  It is not
a probability measure, but is a $\sigma$-finite measure.  You are right, Bernoulli random variables are discrete random variables, but their distributions
*are* absolutely continuous with respect to counting measure, and it is this $P_\theta\ll\mu$ property that makes $p_\theta$ a density function *with respect to* $\mu$.

Your regression setup does not, however, match the iid hypotheses of the theorem stated in L&R, so you are not out of the woods yet.  If you are willing to go to a "covariates" model, where the $(X_i,Y_i)$ are iid, and the marginal distribution of the $X_i$ is known, then Wilks's theorem would apply, but you lose the strict interpretation as a logistic regression.

Comment: Does it not need to be a probability measure even though Wilks' Theorem looks at random variables $Z_1,\dots,Z_n$ that are i.i.d. according to such a family? Also, does it still make sense to take the expectation value with it? One of the conditions of Wilks' Theorem involves the existence of a (measurable) function $M(z)$ satisfying $\mathbb{E}_{\theta_0}[M(Z_i)] < \infty$.

Comment: What is "it" in your "does it not need"?  If you mean $\mu$, the answer is no.  In the case of continuous densities, such as Gaussian location or whatever, your $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure, which has infinite mass and in not a probability measure.  Noone is taking expectations with respect to $\mu$.

Comment: Yes, I had gotten a bit confused, sorry - it makes sense to me now, thanks!

I'm not sure if this should already be a separate question but: What does this mean for trying to find a (measurable) function $M(z)$ that satisfies $\mathbb{E}_{\theta_0}[M(Z_i)] < \infty$? Can it only be a function that is constantly $0$ or $1$, so the values that $Y_i$ can take?

Comment: You are worried about (12.84), which has to hold for all $\theta$ near $\theta_0$.  The function $M(\cdot)$ does, as you suggest, some down to a constant.

Comment: Yes, (12.84) is the one I'm worried about. Thank you! If it is a constant, then to me it seems like (12.84) does not hold in logistic regression. I just opened a new question for it where I explained why [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3796204/does-logistic-regression-not-fulfill-an-inequality-required-for-wilks-theorem-o).

Comment: Regarding your edit to your answer: I have now also edited my question regarding where $p_{\beta}$ comes from and I realized that it is the density function of the Bernoulli-distribution according to which $Y_i$ is distributed. Thus, I believe that it is not the $(X_i,Y_i)$ but the $Y_i$ that need to be i.i.d. and the marginal distribution of $X_i$ does not need to be known.

Comment: The law of the $Y_i$ depends on the value of the corresponding $X_i$; that's baked into logistic regression. If the $X_i$ are fixed given nonrandom unequal quantities, the $X_i$ cannot be identically distributed.

Comment: That's true. However, sometimes (I don't know how often) the covariates $X_i$ are assumed to be some observed random variables in which case they can be i.i.d. drawn from some population.

Comment: You seem to have been right after all. The $X_i$ can be i.i.d. drawn from some population and then assumed to be observed; however, if they are assumed to be observed, then the $Y_i$ are not identically distributed anymore.